# Validator: The value must be equal to the desired value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I check if the value passed is equals to my desired value in the validation phase.

```
$rules = [
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
            'admin_code' => 'required|<the value must be equals to this code "admin">',
        ];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you want to make sure that **admin_code** should always be equal to **admin**, you can use laraval validators like this:

> Regex:/^([a-z])+$/i   The field value must match the provided regular
> expression.

```
$rules = [
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
        'admin_code' => 'required|regex:^admin$>',
    ];
```

> In:small,medium,large Ensure that the value is contained within the
> list of values provided.

```
$rules = [
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
        'admin_code' => 'required|in:admin>',
    ];
```

Comment: Thank you very much @thepiyush13 :)